# Hibernate @ManyToMany has 2 unnecessary columns

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities on a `@ManyToMany` relationship where I wish to link them by their ID.

A `User` can be the manager of many `Task`s and a `Task` can have one or many managers, pretty simple.

So I defined my entities with the following attributes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class TaskEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, name="task_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_task")
    private Set<UserEntity> validators = new HashSet<>(0);

    // Getters & setters    
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class UserEntity { 
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_task")
    private Set<TaskEntity> tasksToValidate = new HashSet<>(0);

    // Getters & setters
}
```

Hibernate automatically generates my table, and for some reason `user_task` has **4** columns: the ID of the `UserEntity`, the ID of the manager, the ID of the `TaskEntity` and the ID of the task to be managed. But as you can see, these are pairs of the **same** values.

How may I tell Hibernate that I only wish to keep the ID of the `UserEntity` and the ID of the `TaskEntity`?

Comment: try to use `mappedBy` on the child side

Comment: The child side being `TaskEntity` since it is managed by a user? And I should map `user_id` ?

Comment: it depends on your business logic, but for me you are right

Comment: @Chris it's up to you to decide which is the owning side and which is the inverse side. I would make the owning side the task. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bidirectional many-to-many relations. You have to mark one side as a parent side and the other as a child side. To do this you have to use `mappedBy` on the parent side.

Refer to this article about best way to use many-to-many: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/